# Accessing the Installed Drivers 

Tags: drivers

I am fairly new .. I want to ask

1. If i can get the installed system drivers of any device/interface card in my Pc and use it in my own applications.
2. If i can then .. Can anyone tell me if i can use the sematic s7 installed MPI drivers for  communication with the Siemens plc with my own application..

I want to use this with c#.net in windows environment

Comment: Wrong formatting of the question, which I improved. And your question has no meaning, unless you tell what operating system your machine is running. If it is a GNU/Linux system you probably can.

Answer (score 1):

The first question needs more work: the drivers, once installed are already there. There is no concept of "getting" them. You can open a handle to installed drivers to perform various operations, if you know how, and the means to do so differs greatly between different types of drivers.

As for the second question: unless you either have source code or documentation of the driver in question, I doubt it would be possible. Of course, the simplest alternative is to obtain a library from the vendor to access the PLC from an application. The library will hide all the tricky parts of using the driver.

Comment: Well Thank for your response.

I would like to know how to get handles of the installed drivers.

And Secondly if someone can guide me to such a library from siemens as i am unable to find it yet .

Comment: Thanks for the answer.